# Formatting a legend with numerical values as labels in python

Tags: python, formatting, label, legend

So I need to format a legend such that the numerical values it contains are expressed in standard form. The code is reproduced below. Note that the legend labels rely on the value of k which is written in scientific notation, although the legend is outputted as i.e. 1000000.0, 3000000.0 etc. How can I change this?

```
V = [4546.09, 13638.27, 22730.45, 31822.63, 40914.81, 50006.99, 59099.17, 68191.35]#total volume injected per well per fracture
Vgall = [1e+06, 3e+06, 5e+06, 7e+06, 9e+06, 11e+06, 13e+06, 15e+06]
for j, k in zip(V, Vgall) :
    t_list = []
    for i in Q_list :
        t = j / i
        t_list.append(t)
    plt.plot(w, t_list, label=k)
    plt.ylim(0,2500)
    plt.ylabel('t (s)')
    plt.xlabel('w')
    plt.legend()
    t_list.clear()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I solved this by writing

```
label="%.1e m$^{3}$" % k
```

instead of

```
label=k
```